# Parsing output of apt-get install for progress bar

Tags: python, progress-bar, subprocess, popen, apt-get

I'm working on a simple GUI Python script to do some simple tasks on a system. Some of that work involves `apt-get install` to install some packages.

While this is going on, I want to display a progress bar that should update with the progress of the download, using the little percentage shown in apt-get's interface in the terminal.

BUT! I can't find a way to get the progress info. Piping or redirecting the output of apt-get just gives static lines that show the "completed download" message for each package, and same for reading via `subprocess.Popen()` in my script.

How can I read from apt-get's output to get the percentages of the file downloaded?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I've often said, use [pexpect](http://pexpect.sourceforge.net/pexpect.html), **not** subprocess etc, to run sub-processes when you need to get their continuous output.  pexpect fools the subprocess into believing it's running on a terminal, so the subprocess will provide just the kind of output it would give on a real terminal... and you can catch it and transform it into any kind of fancy output you want!-)

Comment: Any chance this could work in my C port as well using the posix popen()? Or is there a similar method?

Comment: `popen` will let the subprocess know its output is a pipe, so you're probably out of luck except with commands that are nice enough to let you ask them for "full unbuffered realtime output anyway pls!" and I don't think apt-get is in that elite group.  To implement a "fake terminal" in C under Linux, start with the pty (7) man page, e.g. at http://linux.die.net/man/7/pty - and, good luck (lots of work will be needed!).

Answer (score 6):

Instead of parsing the output of the apt-get, you can use python-apt to install packages. AFAIK it also has modules for reporting the progress.

Comment: Look at /usr/share/doc/python-apt/examples/progress.py

Comment: Any way to do this without Python and without the huge mess of libapt?