# Bash - Parsing output of apt-get install for progress bar

Tags: bash, apt-get

I'm looking for a way to write in a file the percentage and the speed of the download of apt-get (all the line in fact)

[image]

Is it possible?
I've seen this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1692082/parsing-output-of-apt-get-install-for-progress-bar) and the response but I wonder if there was a solution in bash, or if you can tell me the name of this type of output? Thanks

Comment: I suspect you could use `unbuffer` to parse it. Can't test it at the moment though.

Comment: To be truly helpful to others, don't edit your question but provide an answer and accept it.

Comment: Also note that `unbuffer` requires Expect to be installed. `/usr/bin/stdbuf` is in the coreutils package.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the help of BroSlow, I've tried with this script:

```
#! /bin/bash

exec >/home/guillaume/work/apt-install-firefox.log 2>&1
unbuffer apt-get install --reinstall firefox
```

The output is what I would like:

```
Lecture des listes de paquets… 0%

Lecture des listes de paquets… 100%

Lecture des listes de paquets... Fait

Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… 0%

Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… 0%

Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… 50%

Construction de l'arbre des dépendances… 50%

Construction de l'arbre des dépendances       

Lecture des informations d'état… 0%  

Lecture des informations d'état… 0%

Lecture des informations d'état... Fait
0 mis à jour, 0 nouvellement installés, 1 réinstallés, 0 à enlever et 0 non mis à jour.
Il est nécessaire de prendre 35,8 Mo dans les archives.
Après cette opération, 0 o d'espace disque supplémentaires seront utilisés.


0% [En cours]

Réception de : 1 http://bouyguestelecom.ubuntu.lafibre.info/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main firefox amd64 33.0+build2-0ubuntu0.14.04.1 [35,8 MB]


0% [1 firefox 6 959 B/35,8 MB 0%]

1% [1 firefox 198 kB/35,8 MB 1%]
1% [1 firefox 351 kB/35,8 MB 1%]
1% [1 firefox 528 kB/35,8 MB 1%]
2% [1 firefox 751 kB/35,8 MB 2%]
3% [1 firefox 990 kB/35,8 MB 3%]

4% [1 firefox 1 300 kB/35,8 MB 4%]
4% [1 firefox 1 552 kB/35,8 MB 4%]
5% [1 firefox 1 794 kB/35,8 MB 5%]
6% [1 firefox 2 096 kB/35,8 MB 6%]
7% [1 firefox 2 396 kB/35,8 MB 7%]
8% [1 firefox 2 799 kB/35,8 MB 8%]

9% [1 firefox 3 171 kB/35,8 MB 9%]                             511 kB/s 1min 3s
10% [1 firefox 3 575 kB/35,8 MB 10%]                           511 kB/s 1min 3s
11% [1 firefox 3 865 kB/35,8 MB 11%]                           511 kB/s 1min 2s
12% [1 firefox 4 275 kB/35,8 MB 12%]                           511 kB/s 1min 1s
13% [1 firefox 4 706 kB/35,8 MB 13%]                               511 kB/s 60s
15% [1 firefox 5 214 kB/35,8 MB 15%]                               511 kB/s 59s
16% [1 firefox 5 622 kB/35,8 MB 16%]                               511 kB/s 59s
```

Need the package `expect-dev`